# How to keep name of a class using a mixin with static attributes in typescript

Tags: typescript, decorator, mixins

I don't understand a problem encountered during the development of mixin used as a decorator, if a static attribute is included in the code of the mixin my class name is modified in the process.

An interface is defined in one file

```
export interface IElement {
  register(param: any): void;
};
```

In another file my mixin I will use as a decorator :

```
export type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

export function Composite<T extends Constructor>(target: T) {
  return class extends target implements IElement {
    public static asGlobal: boolean; // <- If asGlobal is initialized, the class name is changed
    public static declareGlobal() {
      this.asGlobal = true;
      return this;
    }

    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
    }

    public register(param: any) {
      // Some stuff
    }

    // ...
  };
};
```

In another file, I want to use my Mixin as follows:

```
@Composite
class MyCompositeA {
 // All my class stuff
};

MyCompositeA.declareGlobal(); // <- error TS2339: Property 'declareGlobal' does not exist on type 'typeof MyComposite'.


const testElem = new MyCompositeA();
console.log(testElem.constructor.name); // <- return '_a' if the boolean is initialized and MyCompositeA in the other case
```

[Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/?experimentalDecorators=true&emitDecoratorMetadata=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEA2EC2FzIDeAUMslBAObADOkUAFAA5xRw4BcycIAngJRcAbgHtgAEwDcxAL7FiYXkxQBhESDpQArgjAioAHgAqyALxEZAPjPIQEAO7IGAOletKNLj14BtALr8ZtZG0sQwWiC6wOrIajhMIjTAkMbIEAAekCDiNLHqmjp6UJYMYO4QYFxGgSRkFGBaUCDICJhwNLkZWTnIZVCUFcjA8dh44LkYo-hgRKRkyExaAEaYwAjIdHBga9w0AOKYIktwmFxLIiLYPDbwmDQQksgA9E-IBgC0aDC7B0cnQ7lQMlgCdgAAvCDiAA0vQAFihWu1ciB2ChaC1YTwBuI5mRFisdpttutxBBERRfsdMAwarj5mBYbRnO1Kf9zGBtA86XUKo1mgzaNJ5sg5HSEPkOYV9C43P1PNw+P5acKyDQtMpGK5mXL+EL5qLhfjVusKNQ6NBmKx2F4+MqVS9kABlER4DYNGAwOkG+YOrVzGTSUUAATiCSSkGIiI6yAAsrxQ4lkhAAIKzMgO5OYTDIHC8FptaN0LQe2TyEMusNJyMF3JxhPhiAAITTz1emezufzSLdxc9eOWxu44hwoDOFyuzXZnMDxDrFcTkGTzlJ5IgrOpuvk4o0M0gdCwuBsdkcc-iC5TNOk27ovQg+9GACYjw5Y-H5w3k5et-lLhBnIdKFKO8wAPHBnGvSVdH0ZwUTwTdr1-f8REAvcQMfcCJW0KCoBg1FNyAA)

As I see in the generated Javascript, when the initialization value is added, a temporary class is created in the code and is returned as the new Type.

I have two questions :

- Is there a solution to keep the original class name, I want to use dependency injection. If I create a second class with the decorator its name is the same (the '_a' generated).
- Is it possible to avoid the error of declareGlobal unknown ?

**UPDATE:**

In response to a comment of Aluan Haddad, I've updated the Playground ([PlayGround](https://typescript-play.js.org/?experimentalDecorators=true&emitDecoratorMetadata=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEA2EC2FzIDeAUMslBAObADOkUAFAA5xRw4BcycIAngJRcAbgHtgAEwDcxAL7FiYXkxQBhESDpQArgjAioAHgAqyALxEZAPjPIQEAO7IGAOletKNLj14BtALr8ZtZG0sQwWiC6wOrIajhMIjTAkMbIEAAekCDiNLHqmjp6UJYMYO4QYFxGgSRkFGBaUCDICJhwNLkZWTnIZVCUFcjA8dh44LkYo-hgRKRkyExaAEaYwAjIdHBga9w0AOKYIktwmFxLIiLYPJLIAPS3yAYAtGgwuwdHJ0O5oMnAJ8AAF4QcQAGl6AAsUK12rkQOwULQWhCeANxHMyIsVjtNtt1uIIDCKB9jpgGDUMfMwBDaM52iSvuYwNoINJ5vN6o1mtTaGz5nJKQh8szCvoXG5+p5uHx-BT2WQaFplIxXHTJfw+WQBeysat1hRqHRoMxWOwvHw5fL7sgAMoiPAbBowGCU7Xza2quYyaQCoUaGYAWV4cQSSUgAEEbCHEskIAwYR1kEHo2GIJHancHuHMJhkDheC02om6FpnbJ+PI-XQk8H7aHYwAhKN1mOQeNF3LJluppsZ63Z3P5wuwx2ll2Y5Z67jiHCgM4XK7NJksn0a+Rd+KttPOAlEiAMslr4hVmaQOhYXA2OyODf1iPk6Qn3oQc+jABMV4cNZTjYflfylwQM4hyUKUSgQCIbxnmAF44GYphMuBkHPq+uBvmuVaAcBIigdBsHOCe2i6PozjwngGEAdg2G4S+MHvgRwpEUUpEImu2AzLGUA2Hhow3MQ9g0tgTicTYABKEAwNgujOAMYAAApQCIeiKMoADyMAMJx-CWphVEgQwABEsEGeCnEMf6TEkWREBrnIIlMrRsFvnxAnAEJmn0GJElSWAMkVApSlKeB6kedA2mzGQulAfpRnviZQz0OZBTEVALHkT6-4aFh+k8bgSUiilaU2Y+lHRThpSOfRhGiql1kakAA)) if I create two classes using this function with the boolean initialized, the constructor.name field is the same for any instance created with the two different classes.

I obtain the following inheritance tree with Node (little difference with the playground) with the boolean initialization :

```
_a <- MyCompositeA <- Object
_a <- MyCompositeB <- Object
```

And without :

```
MyCompositeA <- Object
MyCompositeB <- Object
```

I don't know if it is a normal situation or not.

**UPDATE2:**

I've completely reworked my implementation, I've redesigned my class function and I can keep the name of my class as wished initially:

```
interface IElement {
  register(param: any): void;
}

class CElement implements IElement {
  public static asGlobal: boolean = false;
  public static declareGlobal() {
    this.asGlobal = true;
    return this;
  }

  constructor(public pEl: string) {}

  register(param: any) {
    console.log('register', param, this.pEl);
  }
}

type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function Composite<T extends Constructor>(Target: T) {
  let container = {
    [Target.name]: class extends CElement {  // Little hack here to force the name of the class
      constructor () {
          super('Try');
          Target.constructor.apply(this, []);
      }
    }
  };

  let result = container[Target.name];
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Target.prototype).forEach(name => {
    Object.defineProperty(result.prototype, name, {value: Target.prototype[name]});
  });
  return container[Target.name];
}

const MyCompositeA = Composite(
class MyCompositeA {

  f() {
    console.log("Inheritance f: OK");
  }
});

const MyCompositeB = Composite(
class MyCompositeB {
  g() {
    console.log("Inheritance g: OK");
  }
});
```

The only remaining error is that I wanted to add "implements target" in my class definition but it seems that it is impossible (Error: 'Target' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.) [Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/?experimentalDecorators=true&emitDecoratorMetadata=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEA2EC2FzIDeAUMslBAObADOkUAFAA5xRw4BcycIAngJRcAbgHtgAEwDcxAL7FiCTHBo1kAYSy58YZMBxNsecKoyHtRUsiYBXAEaZgCZHThhH3GgHFMI23ExctiIi2DzIALzI8Jg0ENJkNvbuLm5O4hCKrBDevv4M-BZkZGAAFrQAdMo5fpgRyGBQ1nGWZBRg1lAg9WU08chylggiIHSNCGAijIkOTkxYXKOglAWEA61UtPTMrOxcPAKFRUMjIRDlPpQMAOQU1HTQVwA0Vjs4z6UVc5j8fXIDYLwmCg1MNRtZxpMADwAFTqqwAfHUQBAAO7IBjlTGsSg0PZ8ADaAF0CuFEdDpMQYNYQONgMN1CJ9CIaMBIDDkBAAB6QEDiVQgkYNcETKDwhjQ7EQMBcaErSzYHTHMBwUDQOEtZD4iVQShS8ogdgQQlcTIqDnc-B89SaIw6PQGLTGZDa3U6QhkAD0HuQABlWWBsMgSogANZB6AoCZRSZIbooA14ZAiGBx5CmmgasjHMEQqDouUASCKRRo1iBjCu0KgvCuP2IReLzslYHK2aFucqTAMvAYHxozyJdcb-Q1cjIMgpZAV5AgpcwOkiSpVyKgWub%20sNhL6AHlbAArDIt13blEgAAKUBE5YBADlDTRxeumJeJgCgfxyjBJuhECUGAmUFJQ4yF3A9xnKdIYFVC8r2gAEGAoOcW2fERX0BCBngA55CCEfwmhlJ8X1Q9D8QAwkZCHfpKLaDouiXVVVxdPUyOkAY22QABZXgQSZFlIAAQTqHimGZVkIAYBQlDNLjhNEgSLEsGB8mAtNQVOc4REuAAiVAQBKaBWR4WMYC4bcAGktMov46wUUEdBkxkRL4iAACEhMcuTxMk5RVAc3ixLckgyEuOVi2zdSLgYHS9IM5UaRQShTIsqzZBsvynLE-iIIyJQKGqPIbPYyA6BtJFUU47iPOc-j8mkIrZzAG0ACYyrRdLPJc2r5HC7ANMuYrGsMVs7LGEUNzwOserOSKBua4bBVGyZxogOtpzEvNIlmwxJGQYgUTKQMGHWuoACUIBgbBwNdGC0KBbclPW-hQtUk5esirSbS0551vmnMxoAus5GOzaGuana9oOlAjvoU7zsuo8pRu4i7oe%20gnsOKa%20qi5qvt0ehfvbf7DUB7q1LezSova6rKi8HwalxqnMpp-LvjqsnpoprTGcgFzmbp-wGcq-yeb53JWdJ16OcubmICylDbpW6QttwT8uuVnAmvKEKldBobbk2aBrjAMBa2kIA)

Error that I don't understand because we can extend Target but not implement it ???
Sorry for the multiple questions.

Comment: Decorators do not mutate the types of classes they are applied to. There is a long standing feature request for this in TypeScript. Use it as a function instead of a decorator and it will work as expected `export const MyComposite = Composite(class MyCompositeA {});`

Comment: I've tried the solution you propose and it's perfect for the problem of declareGlobal which is now known. The problem of the class itself is always here and depend only of the initialization of the static property, and I don't understand why.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying? You mean the _name_ of the class is wrong?

Comment: I've updated my question to detail the problem I see, if I wan't to use dependency injection I don't know how I will implement it if the types are not consistent using my multiple mixins